# How to solve the problem of making a table horizontally in Latex in \documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a table like the one below in LaTeX. Also, I should insert a long text in each cell.

[image]

I have tried it in two different models, but each has a problem. The two figures below show the issues.

```
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 


\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}

%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\newcommand{\key}{\rotatebox{90}}


\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable*}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}   
    \caption {xxxxxxxxxxx} 
    \label{table:literature}
    \centering
    
    \resizebox{1 \textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \cline{2-5} 
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{white}} & 
            \multirow{1}{*}{\small \bf xxxxx.} &            
            \multirow{1}{*}{\small \bf xxxxxxx} & \multirow{1}{*}{\small \bf xxxxxxx} & \multirow{1}{*}{\small \bf xxxxxx} \\ \hline  &
            
            {\small na1} & {\small na2} & {\small na3} & {\small na4} \\ & 
            {\small na1 } & {\small na2} & {\small na3} & {\small na4 } \\ & 
            {\small na1 } & {\small na2} & {\small na3} & {\small na4 } \\ & 
            {\small na1 } & {\small na2} & {\small na3} & {\small na4 } \\ \cline{2-5}
            
            \multirow{-3}{*}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                    \node[fill,rectangle,top color={white!50!red},bottom color={white!50!red},minimum width=0.64cm,minimum height=3.4cm] (test){\key{\tiny \bf Conventional}};
                \end{tikzpicture}               
            }  

            &
            
            {\small na1} & {\small na2} & {\small na3} & {\small na4} \\ & 
            {\small na1 } & {\small na2} & {\small na3} & {\small na4 } \\ & 
            {\small na1 } & {\small na2} & {\small na3} & {\small na4 } \\ & 
            {\small na1 } & {\small na2} & {\small na3} & {\small na4 } \\ \cline{2-5}
            
        \end{tabular}
        }
\end{sidewaystable*}    




\begin{sidewaystable*}
   \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}   
    \caption {xxxxxxxxxxx} 
    \label{table:literature}
    \sisetup{table-format=2.1,
         detect-weight, % <--
         }  
    \resizebox{1 \textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {},
             cell{2,5,8}{2} = {r=3}{},
             cell{2,5,8}{3} = {r=3}{},
             cell{2,5,8}{4} = {r=3}{},
             cell{2,5,8}{5} = {r=3}{},
             %cell{even}{3} = {r=3}{}
             %cell{odd[3]}{Z} = {font=\bfseries},
             row{1} = {guard}
             } 
              & 
             Ref. & 
             Objective &   
             Features/Classification &   
             Evaluation: No. of Images/Best Results \\
            \SetCell[r=6]{c} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Hand-Crafted Features}       
            & \huge naqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq \newline naqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq & \small naqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq \newline naqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq  & naqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq \newline naqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq \newline naqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq & naqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq \newline naqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq  \\
            & na \newline na & na \newline na  & na \newline na & na \newline na  \\
            & na \newline na & na \newline na  & na \newline na & na \newline na  \\
            & na \newline na & na \newline na  & na \newline na & na \newline na  \\
            & na \newline na & na \newline na  & na \newline na & na \newline na  \\
            & na \newline na & na \newline na  & na \newline na & na \newline na  \\
            
    \end{tblr}
        }
\end{sidewaystable*}


\end{document}
```

Output of the first and second codes in the above document, respectively:

[image]

[image]

How to solve this problem?

@yannisl
My new code after making the settings in the `.cls` file:

```
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 


\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}

%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\newcommand{\key}{\rotatebox{90}}


\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable*}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}   
     \caption {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} 
    \label{table:literature}
    \centering
    
    \resizebox{0.5 \textwidth}{!}{
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \cline{2-5} 
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{white}} & 
            \fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\multirow{-1.8}{*}{\bf xxxxxx} & \fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\multirow{-1.8}{*}{\bf xxxxxx} & \fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\multirow{-1.8}{*}{\bf xxxxxxx} 
             & \fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\multirow{-1.8}{*}{\bf xxxxxx} \\ [.75cm] \hline \\     

            &
             & & & \\ &
             &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} &  \\ & 
             \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} \\ & 
             \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}
            

            &
            
             &  &  &  \\ & 
             &  &  &  \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ & 
             \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} &  \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} &  \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\ & 
             &  &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}          

            
            & 
            
             &  &  &  \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} &  &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}
            
            & 
             & & & \\ &
             & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} &  &  \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.7}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}
            
            \multirow{14.5}{*}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                    \node[fill,rectangle,top color={red!12!white},bottom color={white!99!red},minimum width=1.4cm,minimum height=37.8cm] (test){\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\key{\bf xxxxxxxxxxx}};
                \end{tikzpicture}               
            } 

            & 
             & & & \\ &
             &  &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}

            &  
             & & & \\ &
             &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}
            
            &
             & & & \\ &
             &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} &  \\ &             
             &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} &  \\ &           
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} \\ &       
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} \\ &      
             &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}
            
            &    
             & & & \\ &
             &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} &  \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-6}{*}{} \\ &
             &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-6}{*}{} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}
            
            
            &
             & & & \\ &
             &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}
            
           \multirow{12}{*}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                    \node[fill,rectangle,top color={white!99!blue}, bottom color={blue!3!white}, minimum width=1.4cm,minimum height=12.5cm] (test){\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\key{\bf xxx}};
                \end{tikzpicture}               
            } 

            &
             & & & \\ &
             & & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
           \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
           &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ &
           & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}

            
            &
             & & & \\ &
             &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ &
             & & & \\ & \\ \cline{2-5}


            &
            & & & \\ &
            &  &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            &  & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-4}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-6}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-3.5}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-4}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\ & 
            \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-6}{*}{} & & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\multirow{-4}{*}{} & \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont{} \\&
            & & & \\ & \\\hline
            
           \multirow{-15}{*} {
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                    \node[fill,rectangle,top color={white!100!orange}, bottom color={orange!20!white}, minimum width=1.4cm,minimum height=0cm] (test){\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\key{\bf xxxx}};
                \end{tikzpicture}               
            } 

            &
            
        \end{tabular}
        }
\end{sidewaystable*}        


\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Do not use `\resizebox` on a table, ever! It leads to inconsistent sizes and the result looks just horrible.

Comment: `sn-jnl` doesn't seem to be part of a standard TeX Live installation. Where did you get it from? Can you share a link with us, else we can't reproduce your issue (your table works fine with `article`).

Comment: @Skillmon  ,  I should use `sn-jnl`. Yes, please download it:  [link](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support)

Comment: @Skillmon The table renders correctly as per the `sn-jnl`, which uses booktabs if is loaded else defines its own `toprule` `bottomrule` etc. In lines 1277,1304,1314 change the `\vskip 3pt ` to `\vskip 0pt`. Or better copy the commands and put them in the preamble. I wouldnt advice you do this, it will freak out the editor!

Comment: @yannisl wrong ping? :)

Comment: @Ellie  Please see my comment above!

Answer (score 0):

The booktabs package brought a lot of good to the LaTeX2e community. The template uses it to typeset the table rule. If it is not available they emulate it with their own commands. Change the `.cls` file, lines 1277, 1304,1314 to show `\vskip 0pt` instead of `\vskip 3pt` or `\vskip 2pt`.

The table looks good if not rotated. As rotated it gives you the impression that something went wrong.

I am not too sure, if the editor would be happy with you doing these changes. Better check with them. If you decide you want to do it in any case, better copy the adjusted macros and patch them in the preamble.

Also do not use resize. It makes the table fonts look wrong!

**Personally I wouldn't change it. If viewed in a printed journal, the reader will rotate the book to read the table and in digital form, the pdf reader also allows you to rotate the page. As a rule of thumb though, avoid rotated tables like the plague!**

[image]

Comment: I made the above settings you mentioned in the `.cls` file. But these settings only work for my example table. There is no improvement when I use them for the other table (big table). It doesn't work! I will insert my new code above (in continuation of my question). After running, you can see the problem still exists.

Comment: Just had a look, take the booktabs package out and retry. Otherwise I will have a look in a few hours, as I will be going out. General suggestion also take out the resize and use  data similar to what you have in real  in the cells. Say 2 rows only. If the last cell cannot justify it can also push out the vertical rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want but here what you have directly by using `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}   
\caption {xxxxxxxxxxx} 
\label{table:literature}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[vlines,corners=NW]
  \Hline \RowStyle{\bfseries}
     & xxxxx. & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxx \\ 
  \Hline
    \Block[fill=white!50!red]{*-1}{\rotate Conventional}
     & na1 & na2 & na3 & na4 \\ 
     & na1 & na2 & na3 & na4 \\ 
     & na1 & na2 & na3 & na4 \\ 
     & na1 & na2 & na3 & na4 \\ 
  \Hline
     & na1 & na2 & na3 & na4 \\ 
     & na1 & na2 & na3 & na4 \\ 
     & na1 & na2 & na3 & na4 \\ 
     & na1 & na2 & na3 & na4 \\ 
  \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}    

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

---

An example with columns of width 3 cm.

```
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}   
\caption {xxxxxxxxxxx} 
\label{table:literature}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{cp{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}[vlines,corners=NW]
  \Hline \RowStyle{\bfseries}
     & xxxxx. & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxx \\ 
  \Hline
    \Block[fill=white!50!red]{*-1}{\rotate Conventional}
     & xxx xxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xx x x 
     & xx xx, xxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xx x x x x xxxx 
     & xxxx xx x x x xxx xxxx xxx x xx xx xx 
     & x x x xxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx \\ 
  \Hline
     & xxx xxxxx xx xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xx x x 
     & xx xx, xxxx xxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xx x x x x xxxx  
     & xxxx xx x x x xxx xxxx xxx x xx xx xx 
     & x x x xxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx \\ 
  \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}    

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: You can change the columns types. For instance, instead of `{cccc}`, `{cp{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, after inserting the long and multi-line texts in each cell, the table goes out of the page border. You can test it by inserting the "xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx" instead of na1 and etc.

Comment: Thanks! It is good code, but it could be more adaptive. For instance, it does not work for my table, which has a large amount of text. The texts are intertwined. Also, the table has 12 rows and 6 columns.